# How do I disable all css/theme from ZK?

Tags: css, less, zk

Im using zk version 7.0.2 and I need to disable all styles/themes from zk, then I need to put my own style css. There is a way to do this?

I tried to put some css files but it doesnt change. In some docs I've found shows me about creating my own theme using LESS but it doesnt work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yon can specify the *disable-theme-uri* element in zk.xml, for more details, please take a look at this [document](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Configuration_Reference/zk.xml/The_desktop-config_Element/The_disable-theme-uri_Element).